# Why does String.Format convert a forward slash into a minus sign?

Tags: c#, string-formatting

Why does `String.Format("/")` get converted to "-"?

Answer (score 23):

I suspect that you are using the `/` symbol inside a `{0}` placeholder. It is a reserved symbol used as datetime separator in the given culture. You could escape it, like this:

```
string date = string.Format("{0:dd\\/MM\\/yyyy}", DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 13):

As per [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), `/` refers to the culture's date separator. So you need to escape it. You can either use a backslash as per Darin's answer, or you can quote it in single quotes. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

        CultureInfo da = new CultureInfo("da");
        // Prints 09-08-2011
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(da, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", date));
        // Prints 09/08/2011
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(da, "{0:dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}", date));
        // Prints 09/08/2011
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(da, "{0:dd\\/MM\\/yyyy}", date));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I tried that with all possible cultures:

```
foreach (CultureInfo info in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)) {
  Console.Write(String.Format(info, "/"));
}
```

Output:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////
```

So, that doesn't happen anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your date seperator in your culture is "-" instead of "/". see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73ctwf33.aspx) and this [article](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/)

Edit:

Have you checked your region and Language settings to make sure you do not have an option selected that uses the "-".

[image]

Comment: My short date format is `yyyy-MM-dd`, but `String.Format("/")` still returns `"/"`.

Comment: @Guffa - Interesting... It seems that I was barking up the wrong tree